# How to define C-forward declared opaque struct with a templated C++ struct

Tags: c++, c, templates

Given the C declaration of opaque type (cheader.h)

```
typedef struct internal_data * Opaque;
```

I want to declare "internal_data" as an instance of the template (cppheader.h)

```
namespace Lib {
template<typename T>
struct Internal {
    T data;
};

template<typename T>
Internal<T>* Initialise(T data) {
    Internal<T>* t = new Internal<T>();
    t->data = data;
    return t;
}
}
```

So that the following function compiles:

```
#include "cppheader.h"
#include "cheader.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Opaque o = Lib::Initialise(argc);
    return 0;
}
```

I can't modify the C header. The C++ header isn't exposed, so I can modify that one at will. The instantiated template needs to be POD.
There are multiple opaque types on the C header that I omitted for simplicity. They are all supposed to dereference to instantiations of the C++ template.

I've tried

```
typedef Lib::Internal<int> internal_data;
```

and

```
struct internal_data : Lib::Internal<int> {};
```

but neither compiles.

Comment: Names that start with an underscore in the global namespace are reserved, not that this solves your problem.

Comment: I'm aware, but thanks for pointing it out anyway. I've renamed all the type names for simplicity.
Actually, isn't it double-underscore and single-underscore followed by capital letter?

Comment: @silverclaw In the global namespace, single leading underscore is also reserved.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can make out, this looks something typical of the C to C++ and vice-versa API mapping.

Given that you can't change the C header file, the definition of `Opaque` is constrained and essentially can't be typed to any C++ constructs contained in C++ header file.

It's a little ugly in a purist sense, but you can use `reinterpret_cast` for this.

In the cppheader;

```
struct internal_data {};

template<typename T>
struct Internal {
    T data;
};

template <typename T>
Opaque map_internal(Internal<T>* p)
{
  return reinterpret_cast<Opaque>(p);
}

template <typename T>
Internal<T>* remap_internal(Opaque p)
{
  return reinterpret_cast<Internal<T>*>(p);
}
```

And then the internal `Initialise` changes to;

```
template<typename T>
Opaque Initialise(T data) {
    Internal<T>* t = new Internal<T>();
    t->data = data;
    return map_internal(t);
}
```

You don't mention anything around resource management, but the reverse of `map_internal` can be used to cast the `Opaque` back to `Internal<T>` for the corresponding `delete` when required.

Note: type safety is a concern here (w.r.t. the `reinterpret_cast`), but in this case the trade-off is type safety vs. interoperability. Because of strict aliasing, you should *not* attempt to access any data that may (in future) be in `internal_data`, it is there just to convert from and back to `Internal<T>`.

Worth noting here is [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast), conversion 5, related to the C++ specification 5.2.10.

> Any pointer to object of type T1 can be converted to pointer to object of another type cv T2. This is exactly equivalent to
>
> `static_cast<cv T2*>(static_cast<cv void*>(expression))`.

[Live sample](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4180f3c0392a3dd2)

Comment: Unfortunately this `reinterpret_cast` is strictly illegal in C++. I don’t know what it breaks, at the latest when you switch on optimisations, but I’d be afraid to find out.

Comment: This is how I did it, but I figured that pointer casting might be a bad idea (like @KonradRudolph suggests). I wanted a solution that would still be type safe, but like you (@Niall) pointed out, this might not be possible.

Comment: @silverclaw From [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast), you can do this (the cast), you just can't deference it unless they are aliasing each other (in this case they don't). The `Opaque` is basically a handle (maybe `uintptr_t` would be better, but the C header can't change). Yes, type safety is a concern, but in this case the trade-off is type safety vs. interoperability.

Comment: @Niall Aliasing is precisely the issue here: strict aliasing *forbids* two objects of different types referring to the same memory location (with an exception for `[unsigned] char`). There’s no way around this, and optimisers actively exploit the rule to infer where objects are referred from, and consequently, whether reads can be optimised away.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, correct, strict aliasing results in UB when accessing the object through the cast to value. The code should not access the data through the `Opaque` pointer.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to `reinterpret_cast<>`, you can inherit from a dummy `internal_data`, i.e.

```
struct internal_data {};
template<typename T>
struct Internal: internal_data {
    T data;
};
```

When you need to access the data just down-cast from the pointer to your template type.

Comment: Your solution does work for a single type, but as I said on the question, there are multiple opaque pointers which I omitted for brevity, and wrap different instantiations of the same template. Using your method I'd have to define a dummy structure for each wrapped type and make the template inherit from them all.
What I was looking for was how to typedef an Opaque struct to a template instantiation, which doesn't seem to be possible in C++.

Comment: @silverclaw Ok, I see. Is there a reason why you can't just use composition, e.g. `struct internal_data {Internal<int> data;};` and define it like that for each opaque struct?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe union would help?

```
template<typename T>
union InternalExtend
{
    Internal<T>* internal;
    Opaque opaque;
};

template<typename T>
Opaque Initialise(T data) {
    InternalExtend<T> ret;
    ret.internal = new Internal<T>();
    ret.internal->data = data;
    return ret.opaque;
}
```